# Regular expression for URL Validator

Tags: regex

I have an issue with regular expression. I need to validate for the following url

```
http://50.244.41.23/ 

http://myserver/
```

I have used following expressions

```
Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"(http|https)://([0-9]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"(http|https)://(\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Both are working up to an extent, But it doesn't serve the exact purpose. It gives success for the following strings, But i want the expression to fail for such strings..

```
http://50.244.41.23\

http://256.244.41.23/

http://256.244.41.23.123/
```

Can someone help to create an apt regex validation for the above url.

Thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some example regexes for matching IPv4 addresses; the "Accurate" versions only match valid addresses: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/

By adding a little more, you should be able to match URLs in the form you're looking for. This should match your first (valid) IP address in your question, but not the last (invalid) 3:

`^https?://(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/$`

Comment: I want to validate the port also, for e.g. http://50.244.41.23:8085/... What need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

By using the tokens for the beginning (`^`) and end of the line (`$`), you can ensure that your match is exclusive.

The second regex looks closest. Here is an example:

```
@"^(http|https)://(\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b)$"
```